# How to set diagram color based on conditional expression?

Tags: qgis, expression, conditional, diagram

I'm trying to create a map with pizza diagram, and I'm using the following expression:

```
CASE WHEN  pH >= 6 AND pH <= 9 THEN  Color_rgb (0,166,226)
    WHEN pH <= 6 AND pH >=9 THEN Color_rgb(255,192,0)
ELSE '' END
```

but it inst working. I don't know what to do.

can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `WHEN pH <= 6 AND pH >=9` sounds suspicious to me...

Comment: Looks like it should be `WHEN pH <= 6 OR pH >= 9`, would make much more sense.